# Display a variable in SASS without the $

Tags: css, variables, sass

I want to display the variables in the classname without the $. Is that possible?
like this:

```
.color--brand-primary {
    color: #FF6600; 
}
```

This is my code which i want to optimize for my idea:

```
$brand-primary:                 #FF6600;
$brand-secondary:               #27A0A0;
$colors: $brand-primary, $brand-secondary;
@each $color in $colors {
    .color--#{$color} {
        color: #{$color};
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends a lot on what software you use to edit your code. For example, Visual Studio with Web Essentials allows you to do this.

Comment: It does not matter which software i am using. it is a question for working with sass and the sass compiler

Comment: What would be the point? It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is not exactly the same , but i use the solution from your linked question. thanks. it is a bit more to write in the code defining the array.

Thanks :)